# How to stop a Dispatcher when the event tick?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I need to stop the event connected to the Dispatcher after the event first time tick.
Any idea how to do it.

```
        int closeSeconds = Convert.ToInt32(utility.GetConfiguration("device", "closePopupPrinterAfterSeconds"));
        var dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimerCheckPopupPrinter_Tick);

        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, closeSeconds);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();


    private void dispatcherTimerCheckPopupPrinter_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // stop the dispatcherTimer here, so this method will not fire every x seconds
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher displatcher = (System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher)sender;
    }
```

Comment: can't u just detach the handler using the dispatherTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(dispatcherTimerCheckPopupPrinter_Tick); ? or just stop the timer all together usting the Stop() function?

Comment: could you show me your code extended?

Comment: make the dispatcherTimer variable a global and on the tick event use the stop method -> dispatcherTimer.Stop()

Comment: Of topic: You can use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(closeSeconds)`. However that is just my personal preference, but I think it looks more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the `sender` argument to `DispatcherTimer`, not `Dispatcher`, and call its `Stop` method, or set its `IsEnabled` property to `false`.

```
private void dispatcherTimerCheckPopupPrinter_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var timer = (DispatcherTimer)sender; // not Dispatcher!
    timer.Stop(); // or timer.IsEnabled = false;
}
```